# changing user password with LDAP

Tags: c#, ldap, change-password

This is my code

```
var fullName = ApplicationSettings.DefaultUser;
var userId = fullName.Substring(fullName.LastIndexOf(@"\", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1).ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    try
    {

        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ldapaddressstring", userId, existingPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + userId + "))";
        entry = search.FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry();
        entry.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { existingPassword, newPassword });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        //throw plain exception
        throw ex;      

    }
```

I am getting bad user name or password error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the user to be changing their own password, or the admin to be resetting it?

Are you getting anything for entry, or is the error happening when you call FindOne?

This is the code I use, "Impersonator" is a class to allow impersonation of a domain admin account to ensure the appropriate rights.  you should be able to find it [here](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=impersonator%20Uwe%20Keim).

```
public ServiceResponse ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
        {
            ServiceResponse response = new ServiceResponse();

            try
            {
                var entry = new DirectoryEntry(DomainUsersConnectionString, username, oldPassword);
                var nativeObject = entry.NativeObject;

                // Check passed. Can reset the password now
                entry = RootDirectoryEntry;
                var user = FindUserInDirectoryEntry(username, entry);
                response = SetPassword(user, newPassword);
                user.Close();
            }
            catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException ex)
            {
                response.Status = Status.Error;
                response.Message = ex.ExtendedErrorMessage;
                m_Logger.Error("Failed to change password for user {0}: {1} - {2}", username, ex.ExtendedErrorMessage, (ex.InnerException ?? ex));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response.Status = Status.Error;
                response.Message = ex.Message;
                m_Logger.Error("Failed to change password for user {0}: {1} -{2}", username, ex.Message, (ex.InnerException ?? ex));
            }
            return response;
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Finds the user in directory entry.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="username">The username.</param>
        /// <param name="dirEntry">The dir entry.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected static DirectoryEntry FindUserInDirectoryEntry(string username, DirectoryEntry dirEntry)
        {
            // rip off Domain name if username contains it
            string domainName = String.Format(@"{0}\", DomainName).ToLowerInvariant();
            username = username.Replace(domainName, "");
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)
            {
                Filter = String.Format("(samAccountName={0})", username)
            };
            var searchResult = searcher.FindOne();
            if (searchResult != null)
            {
                DirectoryEntry user = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
                return user;
            }
            return null;
        }



        private ServiceResponse SetPassword(DirectoryEntry user, string password)
        {
            ServiceResponse response = new ServiceResponse();

            try
            {
                using (var impersonator = new Impersonator(DomainAdminUsername, DomainName, DomainAdminPassword))
                {
                    user.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password });
                    user.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0; //unlock account
                    user.CommitChanges();
                }
                response.Status = Status.Success;
            }
            catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException ex)
            {
                response.Status = Status.Error;
                response.Message = ex.ExtendedErrorMessage;
                m_Logger.Error("SetPassword failed for user {0}: {1}", user.Name, ex.ExtendedErrorMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response.Status = Status.Error;
                response.Message = ex.Message;
                m_Logger.Error("SetPassword failed for user {0} by {1} at {2}: {3}: {4}", user.Name, 
                    DomainAdminUsername, DomainName,
                    ex.Message, (ex.InnerException ?? ex).ToString());
            }

            return response;
        }
```

Points to note that might be affecting you:

1. Remove domain name if it exists
2. Retrieving "NativeObject"  seems to have an effect on caching / connectivity
3. This is using "SetPassword" which requires ["Reset Password extended control access right"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746344(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Roger. I need the users to be able to change their own passwords, preferably without any third party classes. Is this possible? i was under the impression that it was.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to drop Impersonator (which is freely usable source code anyway) and swap to ChangePassword instead of SetPassword.  The main question should be:  What line is the exception?  It could be where you declare / assign entry, or where you invoke ChangePassword